# STM32F4 "Could not be resolved" resourses on Eclipse (macOS)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I have a STM32F429I-DISC1, and I generate code by STM32CubeMX and works fine. But, before this I followed some tutorial to run the codes and compiles. I`am a newbie with this.
The projects worked fine, like blinks led, for example. When I go upgraded the my skill and generate other projects, I excluded the recent projects on eclipse and regenerate a other projects on CubeMX, So not more works! All resources shows "Could not be resolved".
I re-followED the tutorials but not has solved.
The follow prints ilustre my problem.

[image]
[image]

The curious is it, the tool settings appears be null.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I can suggest something.

Remove it and install openSTM32. it is basically the eclipse + plugins + toolchain but it imports very well all the cube related project. Otherwise it is a tricky and difficult to get it compiled (too many dependencies etcetc).

http://www.openstm32.org

it is officially supported by STM